# What is use of resources in technical settings in Odoo 14

Tags: resources, odoo, odoo-14

I was checking functionality of resources menu in technical settings under resource. Here is the path: Settings --> Technical --> Resource --> Resources.

But I didn't understand where to use this or what is use of this. I have googled it and also checked Odoo documentation but didn't find the use anywhere. What does this do?

Answer (score 0):

Some modules call on this for their own use. For example, HR apps will use 'human' as a resource. [image]

Comment: thanks for the response but can you please elaborate this a bit more. like what is the use and how efficiency factor is calculated and what is the use and difference between human and material in resource type field? It will be a great help if you can elaborate a little more.